# How to save output of AWS CLI in a variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to save output of an AWS CLI in a variable and use that variable in another AWS CLI, what I did is as follows:

```
taskarn= aws ecs list-tasks --cluster  mycluster --service-name "myService" --region "eu-west-1" --output text | grep "arn" | tr -d '"'

echo  $taskarn;  //empty
aws ecs stop-task --cluster mycluster --task $taskarn --region "eu-west-1"
```

when I echo $taskarn, it is empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following command and it works fine:

```
taskarn=$(aws ecs list-tasks --cluster  mycluster --service-name "myservice" --region "eu-west-1" | grep "arn" | tr -d '"')
echo  $taskarn;

aws ecs stop-task --cluster mycluster --task $taskarn --region "eu-west-1"
```

Comment: When I run this, I get `bash: [the-name-of-my-task-arn]: command not found` error saved as the output to my variable

Comment: @Matrix How to access the values by keys?

Answer (score 1):

Use backquote to execute the command and assign the result to the variable.

```
taskarn=`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster  mycluster --service-name "myService" --region "eu-west-1" --output text | grep "arn" | tr -d '"'`
```

But the correct way is to use the `--query` option of the CLI to extract what you want.

Comment: and what if the result is a dictionary? how to access the values by keys?